# GitHub in vs code

Tags: html, github, visual-studio-code, git-bash

How to remove 10k repository from GitHub in VS code.I just want a clean repository and shows 'Initialise repository' at GitHub in VS code.

I had tried some setting but doesn't got the result.I tried to learn git-bash may be this is the reson of mine problem and also I am very new in coding field so please answer me in a very easy way.

Comment: What do you mean by "10k"? Do you want to remove 10,000 repositories?

Comment: Initializing a repository (`git init`) is used to turn a normal directory on your computer into a *local git repository*. It basically creates a hidden `.git` folder in you directory to hold all the repository details.

Comment: So, how to remove that  .git  folder

Comment: If you want to de-initialize a git repo, just delete the .git folder through your file explorer. If you're on windows, you might have to turn hidden files on, first.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are [using Codespace](https://github.com/features/codespaces?WT.mc_id=vscode-gcom-cxa), your VSCode should be a local instance, meaning one running on your workstation (laptop/PC/Mac...)

If that is the case (local instance), then your repository is also local.
You can delete its folder if you do not need the repository content anymore (or just the `.git/` hidden subfolder).

That won't delete any matching repository created on `github.com` though: For that, you would need to go to GitHub itself, logged as you, [to delete your repository](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/deleting-a-repository), again if you do not need its content anymore.

In both case (local deletion, or remote deletion), you do not need VSCode for that.